# Notation in functions spaces

Tags: notation, convention

I'm wondering if there is a convention for the following.
Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be given and u in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$.
I'm looking for a notation for $g(x,u(x))$ is in the space of continuously differentiable functions. Usually one wants to get rid of the $x$, i.e. something like $g(.,u)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $g(.,u(.))\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is one notation prefered or is there a different notation? If $u$ would also depend on time and $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ this seems to get messy. If it is clear that $g$ does only depend on $x$ I would prefer $g(.,u)\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ over $g(.,u(.))\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, since the "dot" has two meanings in the later expression.
Any remark is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not too keen on "dots" as placeholders.

there is a natural injection, which we might call $\iota_2^2:u \rightarrow (id, u)$ of $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ - here the superscript gives the dimension of the codomain space, and the subscript signifies which place the image function occupies in the list of arguments.  if you drop the diacritics as understood in the context, and use the index notation for the image under a map, then you could speak of $g \circ u^{\iota}$

as stated, this doesn't deal with the second part of your question, but there is still a little mileage in the underlying idea.

Comment: Is your answer different if I'm working on $L^p$ spaces? There the "dots" are quiet useful e.g. when considering the translation operator. In particular, ih one wants to omit the $dx$ in integrals the dot should be there sometimes.

Comment: could you show me in a line? - (it would take me longer to look up). i'm not against any symbolism if it's found useful. merely expressed an entirely personal opinion not based on a systematic study. at the same time there should always be a place for critical attention to matters of notation. a clumsy notation may be a result of a lack of conceptual clarity, and can certainly provide unnecessary obstacles in the learning process.

Comment: For example the continuity of the translation operator in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is often expressed as $||f(.+h)-f||_p \to zero$. In pde theory one sometimes finds $\int a(.)\nabla u \nabla \phi = ...$ if one wants to emphasize the $a$ depends on $x$.